# In Python 2.7.5, how can I check domain resolution if the ISP is hijacking 404 responses?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to validate that a domain name returns an http status of 200, 301, or 302. I've run into a case where the domain name is not valid, however returns a 200 status because the ISP hijacks the 404 response and redirects it to a proprietary search page. This makes the domain name appear valid, when it is not.

```
>>> r = requests.head(url='http://defdoesnotexist123.com', allow_redirects=False)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.url
u'http://defdoesnotexist123.com/'
```

In this case, the user is actually redirected to `http://finder.cox.net` instead of seeing a 404 page. Is there a way to check for this so that I can have my logic fail and consider the domain name invalid?

Comment: Not really a programming question - it has nothing to do with what language or how you code it. As you said the ISP is faking the DNS, for all intents from your computer that *is* the valid website. However, you should be able to fix it by pointing your computers DNS resolver (or your WIFI-router's) at a real DNS server instead of the ISP's broken one. Like 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Comment: Edit: I just realized, this won't be a problem because it's a server-side request. I control DNS. Sorry, long day.

@Anders I understand that the root cause is the DNS servers being used. I'm looking for an effective way to thwart this behavior for users other than myself, where I have no control over their DNS settings.

Comment: I don't know enough about requests, but I was just going to suggest you try something like Martijn just answered. Maybe you could even convince requests to use your own DNS resolver like dnspython instead of the OS. Edit: Or just control the DNS yourself on the server side!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DNS failure is **not** a 404 error. A 404 requires there to be an actual resolvable domain and a server responding, it means the *path* doesn't exist, but the server does. Your ISP is intercepting DNS failures, which is an error condition that occurs before HTTP is involved at all, while 404 is a HTTP error code.

If your ISP intercepts all DNS records and redirects you to a new URL, look for the `Location` header:

```
r = requests.head('http://defdoesnotexist123.com')
if 'finder.cox.net ' in r.headers.get('location', ''):
    # domain doesn't actually exist, redirected to the catch-all page
```

Note that `requests.head()` has `allow_redirects` set to `False` by default, you don't need to set it explicitly.