# Fastest and most accurate way to see if a site is online with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with a fast and accurate way to ping about 1000 websites out of my database once every five minutes. SO ideally it would have to take under 1 minute to complete. So far I have it just running a ping to the domain

```
import os
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                 user="xxx",
                 passwd="xxx",
                 db="xxx")

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM monitors")

for row in cur.fetchall():
   response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + row[4])
if response == 0:
    print(row[4], 'is up!')
else:
    print(row[4], 'is down!')
db.close()
```

I'd ultimately like to get some sort of a response code (200, 503, 404, etc)  i saw you can use `request` or `urllib2` what are the best options for achieving something like this?

This was my request code

```
import MySQLdb
import requests
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                 user="xxx",
                 passwd="xxx",
                 db="xxx")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM monitors")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    try:
        r = requests.head("https://" + row[4])
        print(r.status_code)
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("failed to connect")
db.close()
```

Comment: if you want to do it fast, dont do it one after another, but start a bunch of subprocesses (see `subprocessing` package). I'd go with using `requests` instead of `os.system('ping')`

Comment: requests.head is what I would use if I needed to do this. Have you tried testing to see how long it takes as is? The only reason I ask is that the only way to speed it up would be to start multi-threading the requests I think. And @yedpodtrzitko got an comment in just as I was typing this.

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/34537568/5226168. The issue may or may not apply, but either way has example code for a similar problem using `requests`.

Comment: threads will work quite well here. The CPU isn't doing much so the GIL issues don't apply - you are mostly waiting for the responses from the sites. Alternatively you could use `twisted` and do it async

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone. I am new to python and this is really the only use case I have for it. these suggestions will help